# Evento que identifica quando o navegador é redimensionado.

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, fancybox

Existe algum evento `javascript` que identifique quando o navegador redimensiona a página?

Estou tendo problemas com redimensionamento da página com uma janela `FancyBox`, que perde suas mudanças dinâmicas e volta a configuração de quando ela foi aberta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe sim.

**Javascript**

```
var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};

addEvent(window, "resize", function(){
  console.log("a página foi redimensionada ");
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  console.log("a página foi redimensionada ");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

### jQuery

```
$(function(){

width_inicial=window.innerWidth;
heigth_inicial=window.innerHeight;

setInterval(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth!=width_inicial || window.innerHeight!=heigth_inicial)
  {
    /* seu código */
    alert('a página foi redimensionada');
  }
},1000);

});
```